# How to open website pages with names made of consecutive numbers (http://website/#.html)

Tags: python

so say i had this

```
global a
a = 1       
def newre():
    global a
    a += 1

b = str(a)
print b
op = urlopen('http://website/' + b + '.html')
ops = op.read()
```

It won't work because maybe its in a function I guess but how you make it so that each time the class is run then b in op would be 1 higher than before?

Comment: I'm too sober to deal with this...

Comment: It also won't work because your indentation is wrong.  Please try reformatting your code and edit the original question.

Comment: Who in the world indents their code like that? Ouch.

Comment: im sorry i just took that code from my program. Forgot to dedent some of the region.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to use globals and other things. It is quite simple as what you are trying is somewhat like this.

```
contents = []
for i in range(10): # or whatever
    url = 'http://website/' + str(i) + '.html'
    content = urlopen(url)
    contents.append(content)
```

Also, I would suggest you to start with a good Python tutorial. And Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: ive acctualy been using python for a year now but it was just that one question that i couldn't get passed... makes me sound like i am bad at programming.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your properly indented code, I kind of see what you want to do. I would use a python iterator for this

```
class pageIter:

     def __init__(self):
          self.a = 0

     def __iter__(self):
          return (self)

     def next(self):
          """ Return the contents of the next page """          
          self.a += 1
          #when no more, raise StopIteration to terminate 
          op = urlopen('http://website/' + str(a) + '.html')
          return op.read()


it = pageIter()
for pageOp in it:
    # do something with the next page until something happens
```

(or just simply)

```
maxNums = ??
for a in range(1, maxNums):
     op = urlopen('http://website/'+str(a)+'.html')
```

Comment: Or `for a in itertools.count(1):` if you don't know how far you need to go before you stop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `b` every time you change `a`.

Is it the whole code you posted? It looks like there is something missing here, how `urlopen` is called multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

```
from urllib2 import urlopen

def urlIter(url, pages):
    return (url.format(page) for page in pages)

for url in urlIter('http://website/{0}.html', range(1,20)):
    pg = urlopen(url).read()
    # do something with pg
```

Answer (score 0):

Now, with a generator:

```
def new_url(base_url, maxim):
    i = 0
    while i < maxim:
        i = i+1
        yield base_url % i
```

Then you use it this way:

```
indexes = 10
base_url = "http://website/%i.html"

for url in new_url(base_url, indexes):
    pg = urlopen(url).read()
    ............
```

If you need to call it at different moments and get the next consecutive name, you can use `next()`:

```
gen_url = new_url(base_url, indexes)
url1 = next(gen_url)

.... do whatever here ....

#when you need it, you get a new url calling next():
url2 = next(gen_url)
```